# Rookie Url Rewriting

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, seo

as the title says im a rookie in the 'URL Rewriting' field and i'd like to ask a question that could help many others like me.

Let's say we have an url like this:

```
http://myepicsite.wow/index.php?value_x=1&value_y=2&value_z=3
```

How can one rewrite this url to something like this(seofriendly) without writing a line of code for every page that is generated from those _GET[] variables? :

```
http://myepicsite.wow/index.php/1/2/3
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.php/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /index.php?value_x=$1&value_y=$2&value_z=$3 [L,QSA]
```

Then you just need to make sure your links all look like `http://myepicsite.wow/index.php/1/2/3`.

However, you can already read these from index.php even without a rewrite rule. In your index.php script, you should be able to read the `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` variable and see `/1/2/3`, then just explode that into an array and assign them to the value_x/y/z variables.

Comment: Agree, but i think that a rewrite its more cleaner :)

Comment: The rewrite its working fine but when i do this for example: var_dump($_GET); $_GET is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your `.htaccess`

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^myepicsite.wow [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://myepicsite.wow/$1 [L,R=301]
 RewriteRule ^index.php/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/?$  index.php?value_x=$1&value_y=$2&value_z=$3&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```